# Reading variable name of dataframe into another dataframe using loops

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

So using a for loop I was able to break my 1.1 million row dataset in r into 110 tables of approximately 10,000 rows each in hopes of getting r to handle the data better. I now want to run another for loop that assigns the values in each of these tables to a different dataframe name.

My table names are:

```
Pom_1
Pom_2
Pom_3
...
```

Pom_110

What I want to do is create a for loop like the following:

```
for (i in 1:110)
{
  Pom <- read.table(paste("Pom",i,sep = "_"))
  for (j in 1:nrows(Pom))
  {do something}
}
```

So I want to loop through the array and assign the values of each Pom table to "Pom" so that I can then run a for loop on each subsection of Pom. This problem is the read.table function does not seem to be the right one. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your approach looks like the opposite of what you should do to "get r to handle the data better".

Comment: I'm with Roland but it's your question, what exactly is the problem?  Any errors?  Are those table names actual files in your working directory or variables in your environment?  If they are files you'll need to add the file type to the end, like a csv file it would be read.csv("Pom_1.csv") not read.csv("Pom_1")

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a more specific example of what you want to do withing each dataframe? You should avoid using the inner loop when possible and if you really need to have a look at `?apply`

`nrow` instead of `nrows`

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic solution using a example `data.frame`. The function you're looking for is `assign`, check it's help page:

```
Pom = data.frame(x = rnorm(30)) #original data.frame

n.tables = 3  # number of new data.frames you want to creat

Pom.names = paste("Pom",1:3,sep="") # name of all new data.frames

breaks = nrow(Pom)/n.tables * 0:n.tables  # breaks of the original data.frame

for (i in 1:n.tables) {
    rows = (breaks[i]+1):breaks[i+1]  # which rows from Pom are going to be assign to the new data.frame?
    assign(Pom.names[i],Pom[rows,]) # create new data.frame
}

ls()

[1] "breaks"    "i"         "n.tables"  "Pom"       "Pom.names" "Pom1"     
[7] "Pom2"      "Pom3"      "rows"
```

Comment: And I really, really recommend not doing this.

Comment: Neither do I, but @Forrest38 didn't give us enough information to provide a better answer. It gets the job done, but if it was my code, I wouldn't go that way

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet the problem with your table call is that you aren't specifying the file extension (assuming Pom_1 - Pom_110 are files in your working directory, which I think they are since you're using read.table).

You can fix it by the following

```
fileExtension<-".xls"   #specify your extension, I assume xls
for (i in 1:110)
{
  tablename<-paste("Pom",i,sep = "_")
  Pom <- read.table(paste(tablename, fileExtension, sep=""))
  for (j in 1:nrows(Pom))
  {do something}
}
```

Of course that's assuming a couple things about how everything in your problem is set up, but it's my best guess based on your description and code